# Set number of this brick-built 2015 Canned Fish Toy commercial Award LEGO Duck

Tags: set-identification

I found these two ducks in a thrift-store but cannot identify them or the award show. The text on the stickers says: "Canned fish - Toy commercial Award - 16-18 September 2015 - Ringkøbing" and the instructions are marked: "Design seminar 2015". Google is not my friend :-(

[image]

Comment: Not that this helps much, but if memory helps this duck is a recent remake of an old wood duck that was one of the first, pre-building-block toys made by Lego.

Comment: Edited my answer due to new findings. See if it works?

Answer (score 2):

I looked into this, and it would seem that this is not a numbered model. According to an attendee of the event (who works for LEGO,) there aren't numbers for a lot of promotional sets, likely including this model. I have also searched Bricklink for this. It makes sense that this isn't a numbered set because it was for a seminar.